# SQL Contains with optional search value

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, contains

I've been using the `CONTAINS` function and have noticed some poor query times in a particular scenario.

Cut back version for simplicity:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE 
(
@Keywords = '""'
OR
CONTAINS( fieldname, @Keywords)
)
```

If I remove the empty string check, I can get a null predicate error.

Even if I am providing a keyword, the query takes about a minute to run vs a couple of seconds. The moment I remove the empty string check it is a lot faster.

Any ideas why, and is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Which brand of sql?

Comment: sql server 2014